# .Obj File, broken blending channel issues?

Tags: texturing, objects, import

My .obj file has issues with it's channel settings (I believe). The imported .obj does not properly blend any of it's channels, regardless of a applied vertex color or diffuse texture, in or out of blender, or another program.

It does not cast shadows or have simple shadows across it's surface, coming up as a blank, indistinguishable blob.

Any changes to it's vertex color, through the diffuse channel only colors the object in a flat silhouette color. I assume no other channels except the diffuse channel "exists" with the model now. How do I re-add them?

It's former .mtl file looked like this, which supposedly had all the channels with it:

> ## Blender MTL File: 'S13.blend'
>
> ## Material Count: 1
>
> newmtl Ext1
>
> Ns 96.078431
>
> Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
>
> Kd 0.007127 0.640000 0.000000
>
> Ks 0.249020 0.249020 0.249020
>
> Ni 1.000000
>
> d 1.000000
>
> illum 2

Here's the .obj in blender, and another 3D modeling program:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you upload the .obj?

Comment: https://mega.nz/#!73Y0WaKA!uO7BlC1ZC1VHmZt_h9_gnRp9acVfm0fruJ132lDOe78  --.obj file                                                                                                                        https://mega.nz/#!bqYAzCyL!ZN6e60ndIsZPlNdO2V0AoHXT5GStXgNj6HILfrpYJk --.mtl file